# Advanced calculus proofs

Tags: general-topology

My problem with many proofs is that notations are a bit complicated for me. Most of the time I don't even understand what a proof says or what a question wants me to do.

Prove that $S\subseteq\mathbb R$ is compact iff every infinite subset of $S$ has an accumulation point that lies in $S$.

I looked up what compactness is, but unfortunately didn't understand a single thing.

Your help and examples are much appreciated.

Comment: It's much easier to help you if you have a concrete question. Is your question "what is compactness"?

Comment: I edited your question. Please check it.

Comment: http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~rshah/teaching/2010SPRI-MATH117/HW5.pdf

Comment: I think you will get much better help if you actually sit down with one of your teachers. This question is too vague to admit a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to take a step back to learn and familiarise yourself with the basics. I would recommend searching for good online notes from some calculus/analysis courses or finding a well-reviewed book giving a broad overview of the area you're interested in. That way you can build a good foundation instead of learning bits and pieces on an ad hoc basis without seeing the big picture or motivation. This is not a criticism of your abilities; in fact, you have the most important asset, which is a desire to learn. Patience is key. Good luck with your studies!

Answer (score 1):

You can think compactness of a space as a generalisation of finite set. Hope this crude intuition helps you while learning.